# jQuery wcf data service cross domain insert record

Tags: jquery, wcf-data-services

I have http://subdomainA.domain.com/insert.htm with this jQuery code:

```
        // JSONify the data
        var data = JSON.stringify(data);

        // Post it
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://subdomainB.domain.com/myservice.svc/Surveys", // trying to insert record to wcf data service
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(){ // success}
        });
```

I get 'Access Denied'.  Is there a way that this can be done?

Comment: if the service allows cross domain requests `jsonp` is also an option

Comment: the service does allow jsonp.  can you give an example of how this can be done via jsonp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create a proxy on subdomainA which does the cross-domain (or sub-domain in this case) communication. You just need to create a service on subdomainA which you will call via jQuery ajax and this will do all the cross-domain stuff, with server-side code.
IMO this is the safest and most future proof option.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to add `&callback=?` at the end of your url, have alook at [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)(see the JSONP heading), here are a few links you may find out to be useful

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/
2. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
3. http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/
4. http://davidwalsh.name/jsonp(also includes examples of moo tools and dojo)